# Why jCalendar listener do looping output?

Tags: java, netbeans, listener

After I search about jCalendar Listener (PropertyChangeListener) I found this Code

```
jCalendar1.addPropertyChangeListener("calendar", new PropertyChangeListener(){

   @Override
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
   final Calendar c;
   c = (Calendar) e.getNewValue();
   System.out.print(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
}
});
```

when I clicked (on jCalendar) for the 1st times. (those code work fine)
the output is 1 times.

but when I click (on jCalendar) for 2nd times.
there are two output (just like looping). and so on when I tried for 3rd and 4rd.

> 1. how is this Happen ?
> 2. And is there a method how to solved ?

Comment: Please include where the `addPropertyChangeListener` is called.

Comment: I insert those code on event ProvertyChange.
Right Click JCalendar > Event > ProvertyChange

Comment: so, you add `addPropertyChangeListener` into `ProvertyChange` event?

Comment: that would be the problem.  when clicked twice, it will add two listeners.